# What is the cheapest method to get cloud computing, remote kernels, HPC access, connection to clusters or GPUs?

Tags: parallelization, kernel, high-performance-clusters, amazon-web-services

I want to be able to run parallelisable tasks quicker and on better hardware.  Are there any services that can easily do this with my personal copy of Mathematica?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [remote batch job submission functionality](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/RemoteBatchJobs.html) in version 12.2 of Mathematica makes it easy to run batch jobs on cloud services like [AWS Batch](https://aws.amazon.com/batch/). See [this example](https://wolfram.com/xid/0ihah4xlexcllho87hjuda310pqpy0uqdloyx40-bvt2n) illustrating a trivial job using multi-core parallel computation:

```
In[1]:= job = RemoteBatchSubmit[
  RemoteBatchSubmissionEnvironment[...],
  {$ProcessorCount, ParallelEvaluate[$KernelID]},
  RemoteProviderSettings -> <|"VCPUCount" -> 4|>
];

(* a few minutes later *)
In[2]:= job["EvaluationResult"]
Out[2]= {4, {1, 2, 3, 4}}
```

As of this writing, the largest non-specialty EC2 instance type has 96 cores, so you can specify up to `"VCPUCount" -> 96`.

Answer (score 1):

There has been some discussion of how to run Wolfram Engine on AWS

https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1887758