# Information request re: computing resources

Tags: wolfram-cloud, hardware

An earlier post, [Can I exit a Map over a list of data pairs?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/280645/can-i-exit-a-map-over-a-list-of-data-pairs) described the outlines of a processing heavy research initiative I have under development.

*Does Wolfram or anyone else offer a computing infrastructure platform to which I could upload a notebook and data and run across many computing cores?*

**Scope**

I have:

- 10 sets (batches) of initialization inputs (assumptions) - these can run in parallel,
- 11,500 simulations to run on each set of the initialization inputs - these too can run in parallel, and
- 8,000 sequential sets of data points to process on each of the simulations.

**Current computing platform**:

- Mathematica 13.2.1.0 (home desktop license supporting 4 kernels)
- Apple MacBook Pro w/M1 Pro 10 core processor
- macOS Ventura 13.2.1

**Timing estimate**

I've run `Timing` and `AbsoluteTiming[]` on one set of the initialization inputs over a few subsets of the simulations.

This leaves me with an estimate of well over 100 hours absolute time to run the simulations on a single set of the inputs.

It could take a couple of months to run all the sets of initialization inputs.

I may eventually come up with a more efficient way to cast the problem, but at this point, I need brute force computing.

I understand that Wolfram offers Wolfram Cloud, but it apparently limits computation to 5 minutes at a time.

So again, does Wolfram or anyone else offer a computing infrastructure platform to which I could upload a notebook and data and run across many more cores?

Happy to pay for such a service, I just need to evaluate it with respect to just purchasing more computers and Mathematica licenses.

Thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the cheapest method to get cloud computing, remote kernels, HPC access, connection to clusters or GPUs?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/228807/what-is-the-cheapest-method-to-get-cloud-computing-remote-kernels-hpc-access)

Comment: @rhermans - Very helpful.  Many thanks.  AWS Batch links raise questions.  Does it have MMA kernels available?  Does notebook code need to get compiled?  Pricing seems opaque for small batches?  How does/can WR benefit (good to keep the enterprise healthy ;-)   Seems like a natural opportunity for WR to put together an equivalent to an OOP Facade pattern that could provide an even more seamless interface to such a batch service.  Maybe a deeper review of your links will shed more light on all of this.  Likely worth another question to dig into specifics.  Again, many thx.